# How to reduce the nested 'For Loop' complexity in python?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop

In the below mentioned code,my outer loop runs unnecessarily even if the condition is satisfied at the first iteration.I dont want to run the nested loop unnecessarily.How to reduce the nested loop complexity to increase the code performance?

```
 for i in List1:
   for j in sourceList:
     for k in List2:
      if (j[0]==i[1] and j[1]==k[1]):
       print (i[0],k[0])
```

Comment: Move that for loop to a function, and do a `return`.

Comment: Reduce time complexity? space complexity? Readability? Also do you want all  `i[0],k[0]` matches, or just one. Also you say `my outer loop runs unnecessarily even if the condition is satisfied at the first iteration` but you have two outer loops here which one do you want to reduce the complexity off? Also giving examples of how all these lists look like, and expected output will also help

Answer (score 1):

Considering your goal is to print line by line `i[0], k[0]`, you could use list comprehensions to reduce the complexity of a for loop as follows:

```
'\n'.join(f'{i[0]},{k[0]}' for i in List1 for j in sourceList if j[0]==i[1] for k in List2 if j[1]==k[1])
```

Comment: You forgot a `for`, also not sure how using a list comprehension reduces complexity? You still have 3 for loops

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, I updated my answer. I believe I have reduced a bit the complexity, but not as your answer since you are breaking the iterations as soon as you find the match.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the first condition `if j[0] == i[1]` before starting the innermost loop, and `break` on the first match.

```
for i in List1:
    for j in sourceList:
        #Check condition and only then run inner loop
        if j[0] == i[1]:
            for k in List2:
                #Break out of loop on first match
                if j[1] == k[1]:
                    print(i[0], k[0])
                    break
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `break`:

```
for i in List1:
    for j in sourceList:
        for k in List2:
            if (j[0]==i[1] and j[1]==k[1]):
                print (i[0],k[0])
                break
```

Or use a `def` (function):

```
def f():
    for i in List1:
        for j in sourceList:
            for k in List2:
                if (j[0]==i[1] and j[1]==k[1]):
                    return (i[0],k[0])
```

Comment: I think that `break` will only do half the job: it will only exit the third `for` loop.